# How to access names from a list and display them

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to access two names from a list and display them in the dead() function below. It only displays %s and %s in the terminal. I've read through the documentation on Python lists but i can't see what i'm doing wrong.

```
from sys import exit

name = ["Max", "Quinn", "Carrie"]

def start():
    print """
    There are a bunch of people beating at the door trying to get in.
    You're waking up and a gun is at the table.
    You are thinking about shooting the resistance or escape through out the window.
    What do you do, shoot or escape?
    """
    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if choice == "shoot":
        dead("You manage to get two of them killed, %s and %s, but you die as well.") % (name[1], name[2])
```

This is my code of my dead() function:

```
def dead(why):
    print why, "Play the game again, yes or no?"

    playagain = raw_input()

    if playagain == "yes":
        start()
    elif playagain == "no":
        print "Thank you for playing Marcus game!"
    else:
        print "I didn't get that, but thank you for playing!"
    exit(0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parens to close the `dead()` function call should be moved to the end of the line. Otherwise, the string interpolation is occurring on its return value rather than its input.

Yours:

```
dead("You manage to get two of them killed, %s and %s, but you die as well.") % (name[1], name[2])
```

Fixed:

```
dead("You manage to get two of them killed, %s and %s, but you die as well." % (name[1], name[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The format needs to be inside the parentheses. As is, the format would apply to the return from `dead()`.

```
dead("You manage to get two of them killed, %s and %s, but you die as well." % (name[1], name[2]))
```